# javaScript: Add a default error callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a written a function which in turn makes ajax calls. I have used this in all my pages.

```
    function getFunc(fullURL, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : fullURL,
            async : false,
            dataType : 'json',
            success : successCallback,
            error : errorcallback   

      });
    }
```

And call this function as follows-

```
getFunc(someurl,
            function(data){
                //display data
             },
          function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                //display errors
           }
 );
```

This code works fine. Now I have to add some default error handling code which is for all the web pages which call `getFunc(..)`, but I dont want to go into each web page and do it. how can I do that in `getFunc(..)`?

i.e I need a way to do this-

```
function getFunc(fullURL, successCallback, errorCallback) {
            $.ajax({
                type : 'GET',
                url : fullURL,
                async : false,
                dataType : 'json',
                success : successCallback,
                error : do some default error handling and then call errorCallback  

          });
        }
```

Comment: Use the [`ajaxError`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) event?

Comment: If I'm understanding this right, you need to handle errors that getFunc will throw?  What is getFunc throwing?

Comment: Why are you using `async: false`?  This will **lock up** the entire browser until the call is completed.

Comment: That was a typo. In my actual code its async:true. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @AbhishekAmte: Just get rid of the `async` option altogether.  It's not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not pass an anonymous function to `error` instead of `errorcallback`.  Have the function do stuff then call `errorcallback` when it's done.

```
function getFunc(fullURL, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: fullURL,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: successCallback,
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // Do whatever
            // ...

            // Then call errorCallback
            errorCallback.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean to say is,
if the error is unhandled by the caller - i.e. they don't specify a function..

Change your getFunc to this:

```
function getFunc(fullURL, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : fullURL,
        async : false,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : successCallback,
        error : function(error) { 
             if(errorcallback)
                errorcallback(error.xhr...etc...);
             else
                catchUnhandled(error);
        }

    });
}
function catchUnhandled (error)
{   //place catch all code here }
```